# Does FieldValue.delete() returns an exception if the field does not exist?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have an existing data collection that now we need to add a new field as a flag called `wasImageUpdate`

Most of the documents does not have this field and we wanna keep it that way. 
So we only write that field whenever it needs to be `true` otherwise we want to remove it.

Since we will encounter documents that does not have that field, so does`FieldValue.delete()` returns an Exception if the field does not exist or just do nothing?

Well, I can always check prior to setting it but it might just reduce a line of code and a document read count..

thanks

Comment: Test it once and see with a print command or console.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not generate an error.  If you observe something different, then file a bug with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).